# Unable to properly use public key the generated by Android app for encryption using WebCrypto API

Tags: javascript, java, android, encryption, webcrypto-api

I am trying to generate an RSA key pair for encryption and decryption purposes which public key gets exported as base64 text and then it gets imported to Chrome extension which then it will be used for encryption purposes.
Here is my Java code for Android which `publicKeyString` is saved in database and then fetched by the extension:

```java
class EnCryptor {

    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/NONE/OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding";
    private static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";
    private KeyStore keyStore;


    private byte[] encryption;

    EnCryptor() throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
            IOException {
        initKeyStore();
    }

    private void initKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keyStore.load(null);
    }

    byte[] encryptText(final String alias, final String textToEncrypt)
            throws UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
            NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, SignatureException, BadPaddingException,
            IllegalBlockSizeException {

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(alias));


        return (encryption = cipher.doFinal(textToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }

    @NonNull
    private PublicKey getSecretKey(final String alias) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnrecoverableEntryException, KeyStoreException {

        if (keyStore.getCertificate(alias) != null){
            PublicKey pubKey = keyStore.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();
            String publicKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(pubKey.getEncoded(), 2);
            return keyStore.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();
        }
        else {
            final KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator
                    .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, ANDROID_KEY_STORE);

            keyPairGenerator.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(alias,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_OAEP)
                    .setKeySize(2048)
                    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
                    .build());

            PublicKey pubKey = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair().getPublic();
            String publicKeyString = Base64.encodeToString(pubKey.getEncoded(), 2);

            return keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair().getPublic();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my `JavaScript` code which imports key and does the encryption:

```js
function encryptUsingImportedKey(pubKey,data){


        const fromBase64 = buffer =>
            Uint8Array.from(atob(buffer), c => c.charCodeAt(0));

        var pubKeyArray = fromBase64(pubKey);

        keyMaterial = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
            'spki',
            pubKeyArray,
            {name: 'RSA-OAEP', hash: 'SHA-256',},
            false,
            ['encrypt']
        );

        const encoder = new TextEncoder();
        const encoded_data = encoder.encode(data);
        const toBase64 = buffer =>
            btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(buffer)));

        var encrypted_array = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
            {
                name: "RSA-OAEP",
            },
            keyMaterial,
            encoded_data
        )

        var encrypted = toBase64(encrypted_array);
}
```

but in the end when I put `encrypted` in my `Android` app trying to decrypt it, app throws `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException` in `cipher.doFinal(encryptedData)` line. But every sample text encrypted by app itself gets decrypted without problem. Here is the `DeCryptor` class:

```java
class DeCryptor {

    private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/NONE/OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding";
    private static final String ANDROID_KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore";

    private KeyStore keyStore;

    DeCryptor() throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
            IOException {
        initKeyStore();
    }

    private void initKeyStore() throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException,
            NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
        keyStore.load(null);
    }

    String decryptData(final String alias, final byte[] encryptedData)
            throws UnrecoverableEntryException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException,
            NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IOException,
            BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION);
        KeyStore.Entry secretKey = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey(alias));
        byte[] decryptData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);

        return new String(decryptData, "UTF-8");
    }

    private PrivateKey getSecretKey(final String alias) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            UnrecoverableEntryException, KeyStoreException {
        return ((KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null)).getPrivateKey();
    }
}
```

I also tried to read documentation for supported Algorithms for both sides and that is why I chose `RSA/NONE/OAEPwithSHA-256andMGF1Padding`.
Can you please help me where is my mistake?

Comment: This seems to be [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46042127/9014097). Note that the [suggested workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36708951#comment15) with SHA-256 as MGF1 digest probably does not work because of [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36708951#comment23).

Comment: @Topaco Thanks for the links. After reading them I realized that there might be a with hash function. I tried SHA-512 on both sides but it did not work but after changing it to SHA-1 and specifically `RSA/NONE/OAEPwithSHA-1andMGF1Padding` on Android app which by the way is [not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RsaHashedKeyGenParams#instance_properties) by WebCrypto, it worked! So is there a way to fix this e.g. increasing API version on Android side? Is this really a bug on which side? WebCrypto or Android?